# UE4 Decals have always the same material

Tags: textures, unreal-engine4, spawning, unreal-blueprint, decal

I've got an issue while trying to spawn decals via. Although I have set the material of it, it is spawning a decal with one of the 'basic' Unreal materials:
[Result in world](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBBn5.png) | [Blueprint Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiQ4O.png) | [Material used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBbhx.png)
I have already tried coding it in C++ and using different materials.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the problem. I had to change my material's domain property to be a Deferred Decal rather than a surface